# Tool-tip wrong place in image map

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Here is used jQuery code

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

and tool tip

```
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="Right" title="something"
```

I placed this in area within image map but the tool tip shows in the top left of the screen ! How can I put it in the right position?

Comment: Can you please post the html code along with the image map?

Comment: <area  alt=""  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="1" href="#" shape="poly" coords="96,37,97,79,93,100,62,122,58,109,73,71" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />